# How to solve python model to called by a web using django

Tags: python, django

i'm a beginner for python django, and i try to input my model (the model that i've train at google collab using CNN) for classification of Braille, but when i test the model, there is error like no such file or directory,why is the model doesnt work to classify the image input?

can you solve this? am i wrong with the code?

this is the code :

```
def prosesImg(request):
    filelink = request.POST.dict().get("myfiles")

    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    img_height, img_width=224,224
    model_graph = tf.Graph()
    with model_graph.as_default():
        tf_session=tf.compat.v1.Session()
        with tf_session.as_default():
            models=load_model('./model/BrailleNet.h5')

    testimage='.'+filelink

    img = image.load_img(testimage, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = x / 255
    x = x.reshape(1, img_height, img_width, 3)
    with model_graph.as_default():
        with tf_session.as_default():
            predi = models.predict(x)

    if np.argmax(predi) == 0:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf A <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf B <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf C <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf D <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf E <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf F <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf G <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf H <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf I <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf J <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf K <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf L <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf M <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf N <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf O <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf P <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf Q <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf R <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf S <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf T <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf U <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf V <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf W <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf X <br/>"""

    elif np.argmax(predi) == 1:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf Y <br/>"""

    else:
        predictedLabel = """Classification : huruf Z <br/>"""

    return render(request, 'classification/hasil.html', {
        'judul': 'Result',
        'subjudul': 'RESULT',
        'predictedLabel': predictedLabel,
        'predi': predi,
        'uploaded_file_url': filelink }
                  )
```

Comment: Please don't post a photo of the monitor. Edit your question to post an error as a text and format it as a code block.

Comment: Also, the error is very self-explanatory. Check if the PATHONPATH has the folder where the file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error describes that python is unable to locate the image path. if the image is uploaded at the root level of your python application or in the same folder then no need to append any in the file path.

Remove below line from your code.

<strike>testimage='.'+filelink</strike>

Modify this line in your code.

```
img = image.load_img(filelink, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
```